# Use of undeclared identifier '_AppsFlyerdelegate'

Tags: swift, react-native

I am not an iOS developer rather know bit of iOS and i am stuck at native side of iOS

So I was facing [this issue on iOS](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-react-native-plugin/issues/223)

And I was trying this [suggested answer](https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/appsflyer-react-native-plugin/issues/223#issuecomment-768371228)

Here he says to add this and so I did

```
  // AppsFlyer init here...
  if(_AppsFlyerdelegate == nil){
    _AppsFlyerdelegate = [[RNAppsFlyer alloc] init];
  }
  [[AppsFlyerLib shared] setDelegate:_AppsFlyerdelegate];
  [AppsFlyerLib shared].appsFlyerDevKey = @"YOUR_APPSFLYER_DEV_KEY"; // HACK: iOS SDK is faster than RN plugin
```

but I started getting these errors

```
Use of undeclared identifier '_AppsFlyerdelegate'
```

So I went to my pod file and added this (not sure if this sis correct)

```
 pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'Google-Maps-iOS-Utils'
  config = use_native_modules!

  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])
  pod 'AppsFlyerFramework'
```

Did pod install, again ran the command but the error didn't went away? Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Also (not important) but can someone briefly explain me this code

```
if(_AppsFlyerdelegate == nil){
    _AppsFlyerdelegate = [[RNAppsFlyer alloc] init];
  }
  [[AppsFlyerLib shared] setDelegate:_AppsFlyerdelegate];
  [AppsFlyerLib shared].appsFlyerDevKey = @"YOUR_APPSFLYER_DEV_KEY"; // HACK: iOS SDK is faster than RN plugin


  // React Native Bridge and Root View init here...
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] 
    initWithBridge:bridge
    moduleName:@"FiftyViewsUnderTheAppiumSea"
    initialProperties:nil
  ];
```

Comment: same here... have you fixed it?

Comment: @ruin3936 add `#import <RNAppsFlyer.h>`

Comment: i did but it's still the same :(

Comment: @ruin3936 create a new question or share repo so that I can help you out.

Comment: i'm using the latest version `"react-native-appsflyer": "6.2.42"` but still getting errors. what version are you using?

Comment: nvm, on the latest version, no need to add this `_AppsFlyerdelegate`

Comment: Did you resolve the issue @Cyberduck?